# Parsing Json from JSP response with jquery

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, json, jsp

I have this String response from a JSP:

```
{"status":"ok","tipo":"orden","ordenes":"[{"numero":"15056","fecha":"2006-03-28","proveedor":"101","codigo":"15","orden":"5","fepago":"2006-03-29","marca":"1","razon":"XXXXXXX","importe":"1500.0"}]"}
```

When I try to parse this result to JSON, I receive this error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token n in JSON at position 44
```

This is how I do stringify the JSON (no, I cannot use any JSON libraries):

```java
String ordenObtenida = "{\"status\":\"ok\",\"tipo\":\"" + tipo + "\",\"ordenes\":\"[";
while (rs.next()) {
    hasRow = true;
    if (rs.getString("razon") != null) {
        razon = rs.getString("razon").replaceAll("\"", "").trim();
    }
    ordenObtenida += "{\"numero\":\"" + rs.getInt("numero") + "\",\"fecha\":\"" + rs.getDate("fecha") + "\",\"proveedor\":\"" + rs.getInt("proveedor") + "\","
        + "\"codigo\":\"" + rs.getInt("codigo") + "\",\"orden\":\"" + rs.getInt("orden") + "\",\"fepago\":\"" + rs.getDate("fepago") + "\",\"marca\":\"" + rs.getInt("marca") + "\","
        + "\"razon\":\"" + razon + "\",\"importe\":\"" + rs.getFloat("importe") + "\"},";
}
ordenObtenida = ordenObtenida.substring(0, ordenObtenida.length() - 1) + "]\"}";
```

And this is how I parse it (with jQuery):

```js
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'TraePorOrden.jsp',
    data: dato
}).success(function (msg) {
    var msg = $.trim(msg);
    //msg = JSON.stringify(msg);
    var js = $.parseJSON(msg);
});
```

If I uncomment the line `msg = JSON.stringify(msg);`, the JSON parses correctly but all the attributes are `undefined`.

Please advise.

Comment: can you paste your response that you see in Chrome Developer for example ?

Comment: I think your string (when you initialize `String ordenObtenida`) is wrong: `"ordenes\":\"["`. Shouldn't it be `"ordenes\":["`?

Comment: This is not a JAVA or JSP question. The client does not care where the JSON came from.

Comment: Don't create JSON by concatenating strings. Java has APIs to create JSON. If you paste your JSON into a jsfiddle and click "Tidy" you can see the format is messed up.

Comment: @ChrisG I don't think he's allowed to use them: "(no, i can't use JSONObject)"

Comment: @Ishnark yup, that totally correct, it parsing correctly now! thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The response coming from your JSP is not a valid JSON, first of all.
You are including quotes around `ordenes` array, it should be like this:

```
{
  "status": "ok",
  "tipo": "orden",
  "ordenes": [
    {
      "numero": "15056",
      "fecha": "2006-03-28",
      "proveedor": "101",
      "codigo": "15",
      "orden": "5",
      "fepago": "2006-03-29",
      "marca": "1",
      "razon": "XXXXXXX",
      "importe": "1500.0"
    }
  ]
}
```

I'm not a specialist on Java but on the JSON making function, you're sending `ordenes` array as a string.

My suggestion for you is to don't do string concatenation and use a Java library for JSON creation. Also, try to remove the quotes around the array response, like below.

```
String ordenObtenida = "{\"status\":\"ok\",\"tipo\":\"" + tipo + "\",\"ordenes\":\[;
    while (rs.next()) {
        hasRow = true;
        if (rs.getString("razon") != null) {
            razon = rs.getString("razon").replaceAll("\"", "").trim();
        }
        ordenObtenida += "{\"numero\":\"" + rs.getInt("numero") + "\",\"fecha\":\"" + rs.getDate("fecha") + "\",\"proveedor\":\"" + rs.getInt("proveedor") + "\","
                + "\"codigo\":\"" + rs.getInt("codigo") + "\",\"orden\":\"" + rs.getInt("orden") + "\",\"fepago\":\"" + rs.getDate("fepago") + "\",\"marca\":\"" + rs.getInt("marca") + "\","
                + "\"razon\":\"" + razon + "\",\"importe\":\"" + rs.getFloat("importe") + "\"},";
    }
    ordenObtenida = ordenObtenida.substring(0, ordenObtenida.length() - 1) + "]\"}";
```

Comment: thanks, like @Ishnark says, that correct. Whit respect to JSON library, i can't use it, but i know how it's work (a lor more easier)